# How to make EditText non-focusable when Sliding menu is not out - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have tried multiple things to stop an EditText from gaining focus when its not even visible on the screen. I have a sliding menu that appears when you click a button. But the EditText is hidden right behind the button. So when I click the button it brings up the soft-keyboard but doesn't show the editText because the sliding menu isn't out. Here is the code that opens the sliding menu,

```
            slide_me = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
            slide_me.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.left_menu);
            left_button = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_button);
            left_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    slide_me.toggleLeftDrawer();

                }
            });
```

Now how can I use this to make it so the EditText cant be focusable when the sliding menu isn't out?

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution for this problem? I'm also experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Sadly no. I had to removed the edittext from the sliding menu because it was to much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

to hide the keyboard =)

**update:**

```
        left_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slide_me.toggleLeftDrawer();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think this don't solve the problem, because he says that when the user pushes the button it appears the keyboard because behind the button there is an edit text. windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" makes that when the activity is started (the user navigates to it), if there is an input view, do not show the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the EditText enable attribute to false, and when you hide the slide, change the attribute to true

```
    <EditText 
    android:hint="test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```